# Angular jspdf export PDF formatting

Tags: angular, formatting, jspdf

I have a table that i want to export. It looks something like this:
[image]

This is the function:

```
    public downloadAsPDF() {
      const doc = new jsPDF();

      const specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
          return true;
        }
      };

      const pdfTable = this.pdfTable.nativeElement;

      doc.fromHTML(pdfTable.innerHTML, 15, 15, {
        width: 190,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
      });

      doc.save('tableToPdf.pdf');
    }
```

My problem is that when i export, it looks like this (It doesn't respect the formatting, the spaces):

[image]

Is there something i can do or this is normal? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSPDF only take care of exporting your html code if I remember well. If you don't need to interact with your pdf, then you could use `html2pdf`. It uses jspdf and html2canvas to convert the given block of code into an image and then paste it in a pdf file.

here is [a short video explaining how it works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYZBcqKX4T8).

Comment: Thank you! I will try and tell you the result.

Comment: You're welcome. I have worked with jspdf and html2canvas few months ago before html2pdf. it's wayyyy easier and posess all options available in both jsPDF and html2canvas so don't bother using them.

Comment: I can't make this to work, it's not even exporting anything, idk why.

Comment: Here is the video that explain step by step how to use it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7LoWmGMB7e4 I remember using it to do my job so it should work for you as well

Comment: Ok i finally made it to work, but now i have another problem. it starts from the middle of the page and it's not showing all the table. Do you have any idea? https://imghostr.com/a96804_egg

Comment: I suppose the content is automatically centered. You probably miss configuration in jspdf or html2canvas but i don't remember what I used to do it sorry

Comment: @AndreeaPopa I have created a sandox with minimal configuration but it's working fine for me. Can you maybe edit your questionwith your current code so we can check if everything is ok. Here is my sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/html2pdf-yue3c (Tell me if you can't access it, first time doing a sandbox)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and effort! I've changed my version of html2canvas from rc 5 to alpha 12 because html2pdf was using it (I heard this was the issue) and everything is perfect now.

Comment: Oh well you're welcome, glad I could help :) On my sandbox i just had to install html2pdf for everything to work so be careful not to have collision between two versions